# Cannot curl webserver from outside network

Tags: port-forwarding, port, http, curl, vagrant

I have a webserver running on one of my home computers. I am able to access it within my network, on another computer, with `curl localWebserverIP:8888`. However, I am having issues accessing it from outside the network.

I have set up port forwarding, and am able to ping my external IP address.

However, when I run curl, it says connection refused.

```
$ curl http://76.103.yy.XXX:8888
curl: (7) Failed connect to http://76.103.yy.XXX:8888; Connection refused
```

I opened the firewall temporarily, and now it says "operation timed out"

```
$ curl http://76.103.yy.XXX:8888
curl: (7) Failed connect to http://76.103.yy.XXX:8888; Operation timed out
```

My port forwarding is set up as 8888 -> localWebserverIP:8888. I have a simple web app running at localWebserverIP on port 8888.

I tried the following for support but got no resolution:[Can't access web server](https://superuser.com/questions/576590/cant-access-web-server)

I can't access any port on http://76.103.yy.XXX:{>8000}. However, port 8888, the one with my webserver, hangs. The other ports simply quit immediately.

edit: Running the webserver on vagrant in bridged mode.

edit2: ultimately, there is a problem with my ISP. check comments for details. closing.

Comment: I would guess that your home router is forwarding to the wrong local IP address. Check carefully!

Comment: Thanks, but I am positive I have the correct local IP.

Comment: What OS is the server running?

Comment: @Paul, I disabled the firewall on the VM running the webserver, and host machine running the VM, and the router. Not feeling safe right now.

Comment: @ekaj, basically the same as curl. the correct port hangs but a random port immediately quits.

Comment: ok this might be a red flag, but when i do netstat -tpln on the webserver machine (a bridged VM), i see that the service is running on 0.0.0.0:8888. Is that an issue?

Comment: @ekaj, then why can I access the webserver at the local ip of 192.168.1.100:8888 from another machine on my network? I'm not accessing 0.0.0.0:8888.

Comment: I'm running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888`

Comment: @ekaj, yup, I can! In that case, I can use either the external IP or the internal IP address, and both work! The only other thing I can think of that might be an issue is that my external network right now is a mobile hotspot with verizon. Not sure if they would block anything. But seeing as how requesting the wrong port changes from hanging to "quitting" immediately, it seems as though my packets are still getting through to the router at least

Comment: @barrrista The timeout suggest they are getting through.  The problem is probably that there is no routing path back out.  Can you access the internet from the VM?

Comment: @Paul, a curl from the vm to asdf.com took 6 seconds. a curl from the host of the VM took .167 seconds. It is interesting to me why there is a big difference.

Comment: @Paul, I did a traceroute to my external address and it failed within comcast's network, before ever reaching my router. I think this might be a problem with my ISP?

Comment: @Paul, ok it's suddenly working - sorta. The page prints out "hi", as intended but I still see "Resolving host" as chrome is waiting for something to load. Definitely feels like something wrong with my ISP.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Closing this. The page now loads completely, but sometimes barely. This symptom as well as the traceroute definitely points to an ISP issue.